# Characteristics of First-Order PDEs Example: How Was This Integration Done?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

From *Essential Partial Differential Equations*, by Griffiths, Dold, and Silvester:

> *Example 4.2* (Half-plane problem) Solve the PDE $pux + quy = f(x, y)$ (with $p$ and $q$ constant) in the domain $\alpha x + \beta y > 0$ given that $u = g(x)$ on the line $\mathcal{l} : \alpha x + \beta y = 0$, where $q > 0$ and $\beta > 0$.
>
> As in the previous example, the characteristic equations (4.4) are readily solved to give
>
> $$x = pt + C_1, y = qt + C_2$$
>
> where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constant along any characteristic. The assumption $q > 0$ means that $y$ increases along a characteristic as $t$ increases -- thus the parameter $t$ may be viewed as a time-like variable. This is illustrated in Fig. 4.1 where the arrows on the characteristics indicate increasing t.
>
> In order to determine the solution at a point $P(x, y)$, we trace the characteristic through this point backwards in $t$ until it intersects the line $\mathcal{l}$. We shall suppose that this occurs at the point $Q$ having coordinates $x = \beta s$, $y = − \alpha s$ when $t = 0$. Then, from (4.8), we find $C_1 = \beta s$, $C_2 = − \alpha s$. Here $s$ is a parameter that plays a role similar to that of $k$ in the previous example. It varies along the line l and each choice of s selects a different characteristic:
>
> $$x = pt + \beta s, y = qt − \alpha s$$
>
> Next we consider the last characteristic equation
>
> $$\frac{du}{dt} = f(x(s, t), y(s, t))$$
>
> Integrating gives
>
> $$u(s, t) = u(s, 0) + \int_0^t f(x(s, t'), y(s, t')) \ dt'$$
>
> Here $u(s, 0)$ is a constant along any characteristic but varies from one characteristic to another.

My question is, how did the author get

$$u(s, t) = u(s, 0) + \int_0^t f(x(s, t'), y(s, t')) \ dt'$$

by integrating?

Where did the $u(s, 0)$ term come from? And how was $\int_0^t f(x(s, t'), y(s, t')) \ dt'$ calculated by integration? For instance, I have never seen something written like $dt'$?

Thank you for any explanation you could offer.

Comment: Keep in mind that $t'$ doesn't denote a derivative- it's just another variable.  It might help to replace it with something like $z$.  You can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to see that this solution satisfies the differential equation.  You can also check that the formula has the correct value for $u(s,t)$ at the initial time $t=0$.

Comment: What's the derivative with respect to $t$ of $u(s,0)$?  What's the derivative with respect to $t$ of the integral in the second term?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, the $u(s, 0)$ is from using the **part 2** fundamental theorem of calculus! And $\int_0^t f(x(s, t'), y(s, t')) \ dt'$ is from the part 1 fundamental theorem of calculus. Using the part 2 fundamental theorem of calculus, we get $u(s, t) - u(s, 0)$ for the left-hand side integration.